# JSON stringify converting complete array element to key of an array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, stringify, sendbeacon

I am trying to attach `sendBeacon` method to one of the page in my web application. I tried to send `request` using a simple `AJAX` method and via `sendBeacon()` method. Both are giving different results and none is usable. Please suggest.

**html.php**

```
<body>
    <button onclick="setzero();">
        click me
    </button>
    <script>
        function setzero(){
            var settings = {
            "url":"ttstt.php",
            "method":"POST",
            "data": JSON.stringify({"val":0})
            };
            $.ajax(settings).done(function(e){console.log(e);});
        }
      
        window.addEventListener("unload", function() {  
          navigator.sendBeacon("ttstt.php", JSON.stringify({"val":1}));
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**ttstt.php**

```
$val = ($_POST);
print_r($val);
```

When I click the button on `html.php` I get the following result.
**!! Please note that the complete array is in the key portion. !!**

```
Array
(
    [{"val":0}] => 
)
```

When I reload the page to initiate the `sendBeacon()`, I get `[]` as a result.

Comment: `"data": {"val":0}` is enough.

Comment: How do I use this is php code? Value is in the key portion of associative array. And moreover sendBeacon is not even sending the array? I am more concerned about sendBeacon result.

Comment: The same - `print_r($_POST)` and see what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the following in my PHP code

```
$val = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($val);
echo $json['val'];       //This gives output as 0, which I was looking for.
```

Also same code works with sendBeacon() data also.